# Bash script that adds quantities by categories

Tags: bash, shell

I need help with a bash script that adds quantity by category.

Input lines and output lines are of the form "category" "quantity"

Example file:

```
Mustard 6
Apple 4
Mustard 2
```

Output should be:

```
Mustard 8
Apple 4
```

The order doesn't matter, it could be:

```
Apple 4
Mustard 8
```

The files/input will be in the correct format, with the 2nd field being a number (possibly negative)

Use sh shell script only, no awk, python, perl etc.

I need to start the code with cat "$@" |...

What I have so far:

```
cat "$@" | while read line
do
```

if first word on first line = first word on second line, add $2 and remove that line, repeat for all lines

```
done
```

I am not sure how do implement inbetween the while loop, I am thinking about an associative array, I am almost certain that is what I need.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we can use `bash` but not `awk`:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A c
cat "$@" | { while read item amount
do
    ((c[$item]+=$amount))
done

for i in "${!c[@]}"
do
    echo "$i ${c[$i]}"
done
}
```

This produces:

```
Mustard 8
Apple 4
```

If we were not so restricted, we could use `awk` which makes things easier:

```
awk '{ c[$1]+=$2 } END { for (i in c) { print i,c[i] } }' groceries
```

Or, if we want to start with `cat "$@"`, then:

```
cat "$@" | awk '{ c[$1]+=$2 } END { for (i in c) { print i,"=",c[i] } }'
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using awk? I was required to use cat "$@" to begin and pipe it with something else.

Comment: `awk` is easily adapted to the `cat "$@"` requirement.  Are you also _required_ not to use `awk`?

Comment: I believe so, awk was specifically mentioned to be avoided. I am taking an intro course so we haven't gotten to awk yet, just the basic stuff. I understand what I need to do: while reading the file by line, for loop through the lines and check for duplicates, then add the values for $2, I am just not sure how to implement it.

Comment: does adding an ! in front of the array output all the index?

Comment: @NickGong Yes.  Without it, it would return the amounts, not the categories.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it didn't require a giant block of code but I just couldn't do it without writing 500 lines :P

Comment: I was testing the code today, it outputs: `0 12`. I am not sure why it does this.

Comment: @NickGong Please check that the `declare -A c` line is at the top of the script, written correctly with the `-A` capitalized.  Without that line, the output becomes `0 12`.  The reason is that `declare -A c` makes `c` into an _associative array_ rather than an ordinary _indexed array_.

Comment: Oh i see, thanks for the heads up, everything works fine now!